# Multiple mail attachment - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, email-attachments

Hi i am doing an app in phonegap which need to have multiple attachment but i am unable to have multiple attachment. Any solution for this. My code are as below:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="emailcomposer.js"></script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
            function deviceready() {
                console.log("Device ready");
            }

            function composeText(){
                var attachPath; 
                var attachFile= new Array();
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("RepairMyCar", {
                        create: true
                    }, function(directory) {
                        console.log("Final 63" + directory.fullPath);
                        attachPaths = directory.fullPath;
                        var attachPath=attachPaths.slice(7,attachPaths.length);
                        var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
                        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                            var i;
                            for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                                console.log(entries[i].name);
                                attachFile[i] ='"' + attachPath + "/" + entries[i].name + '"';
                            }
                        }, function (error) {
                            alert(error.code);
                        });

                    });
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
                });

                //var vehiclemake = document.getElementById("vehiclemake");
                //var strUser = vehiclemake.options[vehiclemake.selectedIndex].value;
                var vehiclemileage = document.getElementById('vehiclemileage').value;
                var vehiclemodel = document.getElementById('vehiclemodel').value;
                var message1 = document.getElementById('message_body').value;
                console.log(message1);
                console.log("Composer" + attachFile);
                var newAttachment = attachFile.toString();
                console.log(newattachment);
                window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer(
                    "Get an Estimate",
                     "Model of Vehicle " + " " + vehiclemodel +  "Mileage of Vehicle " + " " + vehiclemileage + message1,
                    ["sth@sth.com"],
                    [],
                    [],
                    true,
                    [newAttachment]
                    );
            //exit the app after clicking this button
            //navigator.app.exitApp();
            // navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess,fail);
            // function onSuccess(){
            // }
            // function fail(){
            // }
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }



    /***********************************************
    * Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
    * This notice MUST stay intact for use
    * Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
    ***********************************************/

    var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
        var today=new Date()
        var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
        var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
        var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
        for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
            dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
    dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
    for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
        monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
    monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
    var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
    for (var y=0; y<25; y++){
        yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
        thisyear-=1
    }
    yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Get a Repair Estimate</h1>
            <div class="main-content">
    <p>
                Please Enter the Year, Make, Model and Mileage of Your Vehicle and any other information we should know.
                </p>
                <form class="vehicle-detail-form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Year of Vehicle: </label>
                        <form action="" name="someform">
                        <select id="daydropdown">
                        </select> 
                        <select id="monthdropdown">
                        </select> 
                        <select id="yeardropdown">
                        </select> 
                    </form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

    //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
    window.onload=function(){
        populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
    }
    </script>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Vehicle Year Selection -->


    <li><label>Make of Vehicle:</label>

    <!-- Model of Vehicle Selection -->
    </li>
    <li><label>Model of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pnum" id = "vehiclemodel">
    </li>
    <li><label>Mileage of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="number" name="pnum" id = "vehiclemileage"></li>
    <li>
        <textarea  name="message_body" id = 'message_body'  placeholder="Add Notes here(if any)"></textarea>
    </li>
    </form>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="large-button-wrapper">
    <button onclick="composeText();">Get Your Estimate</button>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using EmailComposer.java as below

```
/**
 *
 * Phonegap Email composer plugin for Android with multiple attachments handling
 *
 * Version 1.0
 *
 * Guido Sabatini 2012
 *
 */

package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.Html;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.LOG;

public class EmailComposer extends CordovaPlugin {

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
if ("showEmailComposer".equals(action)) {

try {
JSONObject parameters = args.getJSONObject(0);
if (parameters != null) {
sendEmail(parameters);
}
} catch (Exception e) {

}
callbackContext.success();
return true;
}
return false; // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
}

private void sendEmail(JSONObject parameters) {

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

//String callback = parameters.getString("callback");

boolean isHTML = false;
try {
isHTML = parameters.getBoolean("bIsHTML");
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling isHTML param: " + e.toString());
}

if (isHTML) {
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
} else {
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
}

// setting subject
try {
String subject = parameters.getString("subject");
if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling subject param: " + e.toString());
}

// setting body
try {
String body = parameters.getString("body");
if (body != null && body.length() > 0) {
if (isHTML) {
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
} else {
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling body param: " + e.toString());
}

// setting TO recipients
try {
JSONArray toRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("toRecipients");
if (toRecipients != null && toRecipients.length() > 0) {
String[] to = new String[toRecipients.length()];
for (int i=0; i<toRecipients.length(); i++) {
to[i] = toRecipients.getString(i);
}
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling toRecipients param: " + e.toString());
}

// setting CC recipients
try {
JSONArray ccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("ccRecipients");
if (ccRecipients != null && ccRecipients.length() > 0) {
String[] cc = new String[ccRecipients.length()];
for (int i=0; i<ccRecipients.length(); i++) {
cc[i] = ccRecipients.getString(i);
}
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling ccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
}

// setting BCC recipients
try {
JSONArray bccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("bccRecipients");
if (bccRecipients != null && bccRecipients.length() > 0) {
String[] bcc = new String[bccRecipients.length()];
for (int i=0; i<bccRecipients.length(); i++) {
bcc[i] = bccRecipients.getString(i);
}
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling bccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
}

// setting attachments
try {
JSONArray attachments = parameters.getJSONArray("attachments");
if (attachments != null && attachments.length() > 0) {
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
for (int i=0; i<attachments.length(); i++) {
try {
File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));
if (file.exists()) {
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
uris.add(uri);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error adding an attachment: " + e.toString());
}
}
if (uris.size() > 0) {
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling attachments param: " + e.toString());
}

this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, emailIntent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
// TODO handle callback
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
LOG.e("EmailComposer", "ResultCode: " + resultCode);
// IT DOESN'T SEEM TO HANDLE RESULT CODES
}
    }
```

An my error stacktrace is

```
10-01 14:03:16.129: W/Bundle(7685): Key android.intent.extra.TEXT expected ArrayList<CharSequence> but value was a android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.os.Bundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(Bundle.java:1326)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.content.Intent.getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(Intent.java:4571)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7066)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1425)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:825)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.plugin.EmailComposer.sendEmail(EmailComposer.java:158)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.plugin.EmailComposer.execute(EmailComposer.java:37)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:66)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:215)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:51)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$14000(WebViewCore.java:72)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:2996)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:914)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:813)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$900(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
 10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1433)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1069)
10-01 14:03:16.149: W/Bundle(7685):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Help!!!! I have seen these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776416/java-lang-classcastexception-android-text-spannablestringbuilder-cannot-be-cast) and [link two](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38303).

Comment: https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer this is the plugin you are looking for it has separate function called attachments: provide full path of the attachment

Comment: I am facing this error 10-01 15:09:48.570: E/EmailComposer(17170): Error handling attachmentsData param: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't had to under go any edit as per the link i got when googled. I just had some typos and path mistake.

My code is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="emailcomposer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
            function deviceready() {
                console.log("Device ready");
            }

            function composeText(){
                var attachPath; 
                var attachFile= new Array();
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("MyAppFolder", {
                        create: true
                    }, 
        function(directory) {
            console.log("Final 63" + directory.fullPath);
            attachPaths = directory.fullPath;
            var attachPath=attachPaths.slice(7,attachPaths.length);
            var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    console.log(entries[i].name);
attachFile[i] =attachPath + "/" + entries[i].name;
                            }
                            console.log(attachFile);
                        }, 
                        function (error) {
                            alert(error.code);
                        });

                    });
                }, function(error) {
        alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
                });
        var dated, fnamed, phoned, emailed;
     if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  dated = localStorage.date;
  fnamed = localStorage.fname;
  phoned = localStorage.phone;
  emailed= localStorage.email;
 }

var vehiclemileage = document.getElementById('vehiclemileage').value;
var vehiclemodel = document.getElementById('vehiclemodel').value;
var message1 = document.getElementById('message_body').value;
var vechicleyear = document.getElementById("yeardropdown");
var strUser = vechicleyear.options[vechicleyear.selectedIndex].value;
var vehiclemake = document.getElementById("vehiclemake");
var makevehicle = vehiclemake.options[vehiclemake.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(attachFile);

var newattachment = attachFile.toString();
                    window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(null,
                    "Get an Estimate",
                     "Date" + dated + "First Name " + fnamed + "Phone Number" + phoned + "Email Address" + emailed +  "Year of Vehicle" + strUser + "Make of Vehicle" + makevehicle +  "Model of Vehicle " + " " + vehiclemodel +  
                     "Mileage of Vehicle " + " " + vehiclemileage + message1,
                    ["sth@sth.com"],
                    [],
                    [],
                    true,
                    attachFile
                    );
                //Clear LoccalStorage
                localStorage.clear();
            //exit the app after clicking this button
            //navigator.app.exitApp();
            // navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess,fail);
            // function onSuccess(){
            // }
            // function fail(){
            // }
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    /***********************************************
    * Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
    * This notice MUST stay intact for use
    * Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
    ***********************************************/

    function populatedropdown(yearfield){
        var today=new Date()
        var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
        for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
            //Select Year
    var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
    for (var y=0; y<25; y++){
        yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
        thisyear-=1
    }
    yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Get a Repair Estimate</h1>
            <div class="main-content">
    <p>Please Enter the Year, Make, Model and Mileage of Your Vehicle and any other information we should know.
</p>
<form class="vehicle-detail-form">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <label>Year of Vehicle: </label>
        <form action="" name="someform">
                        <select id="yeardropdown">
                        </select> 
                    </form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

    //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
    window.onload=function(){
        populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
    }
    </script>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Vehicle Year Selection -->


    <li><label>Make of Vehicle:</label>

    <!-- Model of Vehicle Selection -->


    </li>
    <li><label>Model of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vehiclemodel" id = "vehiclemodel">
    </li>
    <li><label>Mileage of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="number" name="vehiclemileage" id = "vehiclemileage"></li>
    <li>
        <textarea  name="message_body" id = 'message_body'  placeholder="Add Notes here(if any)"></textarea>
    </li>
    </form>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="large-button-wrapper">
    <button onclick="composeText();">Get Your Estimate</button>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <!-- -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

The problem is that HTML.fromHtml(body) returns a android.text.SpannableStringBuilder which cannot be casted to java.util.ArrayList.
Try to replace that line of code with

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body).toString());
```

or with

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(Html.fromHtml(body).toString());
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, list);
```

Comment: it did resolved the error but i can't see body that i have seen previously and also attachment is also not done.